# Linked Server query to Oracle fails on very wide table - adjusting FetchSize doesn't resolve the problem

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, oracle-19c

We're using a Linked Server connection to Oracle 19c, using the 21.3 Oracle Client (64 bit). We're running on SQL 2019.

This connection works fine for all the tables we want to query except one, which is very very wide (494 fields). Our query that fails is:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM openquery (MyLinkedServer, 'select * from abc.MyVeryWideTable')
```

With this error message:

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MyLinkedServer"
> reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic
> failure. Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 15 Cannot fetch a row from
> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MyLinkedServer".

However this works:

```
SELECT TOP 99 * FROM openquery (MyLinkedServer, 'select * from abc.MyVeryWideTable')
```

Investigating this issue led us to learn about the FetchSize registry setting, which can also be set through the @provstr parameter when creating the Linked Server.  It defaults to 100, hence the query works at 99 rows but fails at 100.  One forum we found suggested just changing the value to 101 would be sufficient to cover all query sizes -- but for us it only gave us 1 more row. As we have ~91,000 rows in the table to select, I thought it would just be as simple as setting FetchSize to 100000 (it accepts a max value of ~400m according to Oracle), and everything would work fine. However through experimentation we found that our query would fail with any FetchSize larger than 3602, with this error:

> Cannot execute the query "select * from abc.MyVeryWideTable" against OLE
> DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle"

This was definitely related to the table width -- if we changed the `SELECT *` to be just `SELECT Col1, Col2` we were able to set the FetchSize to 10,000,000 and it still worked fine. (Somewhere between 10m and 100m we start getting a memory allocation error)

Before you ask, yes -- we need all 494 fields.  (Sigh)

So ---- how can we successfully SELECT all ~91k records and all 494 fields, given that we can't use a FetchSize of > 3602?

One more clue -- this all worked fine on our old environment, SQL 2014 running Oracle Client 11.2.0 to Oracle 19c. There was no need to set FetchSize there at all -- in the registry it is still at it's original default of 100.

Comment: Was the old SQL instance the same memory and such? Have you tried using the older Oracle driver? Trying to keep ~91k very wide rows in memory seems a bit much. You can't import them into a temp table or anything?

Comment: Hi Sean - RAM is the same on both old and new SQL. The SELECT is actually feeding an INSERT INTO statement, so we're writing the data immediately. Considered doing a batch process, i.e. importing maybe 1k rows at a time -- but there is no good key or timestamp field to keep track of what has been imported already and what to request for the next batch.  No, haven't tried the old driver -- I've been averse to using something so old compared to the Oracle 19c server. Will try that if I run out of other options. Currently trying to get the business to accept fewer fields :D